# Similar xhr request taking different times in chrome and firefox

Tags: jquery, performance, google-chrome, firefox, xmlhttprequest

I am making same requests from my website in chrome and firefox. I observed that they have different sizes and the time taken is very different. Firefox is taking a long time compared to chrome. I am fine with size because the difference is just in bytes and not very significant. But time period is causing very bad UX. Can someone tell me what all I can check on? Thank you very much.

PS. I have checked for the same without browser extensions. It still takes longer in firefox than chrome.

[image: This is in firefox]

[image: This is in chrome]

Comment: Do you get the same results if you clear or disable the cache in both browsers first?

Comment: @ocrdu Not exactly the same timings, but yeah I see significant difference between chrome and firefox with firefox taking longer duration